# i want to saveChange my table from visual stedio to database. But i can not to saveing

Tags: javascript, datetime, c#-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br9or.png)

I want to add a new item to the table - I encountered a saveChange error -

Of course, in the sign database

I emptied re-creadied...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDIht.png)

context.InternalContext.HistoryContextFactory

Local = The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

Sql = "SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[pkID] AS [pkID], \r\n    [Extent1].[fkDocID] AS [fkDocID], \r\n    [Extent1].[SDate] AS [SDate], \r\n    [Extent1].[EDate] AS [EDate], \r\n    [Extent1].[fkPID] AS [fkPID], \r\n    [Extent1].[fkVTID] AS [fkVTID], \r\n    [Extent1]...

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at hospital.Controllers.HomeController.addvisit(Int32 docid, Int32 visitid, String visitdatetime, String pid) in D:\Cili\hospital\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 128
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2()

Inner Exception 1:
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception 2:
SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table_Visit_Table_Patient". The conflict occurred in database "6321_hospital", table "dbo.Table_Patient", column 'pkID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I followed the values ​​specified in the database. For example, for the national code in the database, char(10)

or phone

> char(11)

```
  Double Duration = context.View_PerDoctorsID.Where(x => x.fkDocID == docid && x.fkVisitID == visitid).Select(x => x.Duration).Single();

            Table_Visit nv = new Table_Visit();

            nv.fkDocID = docid;
            nv.SDate = a;
            nv.EDate = a.AddMinutes(Duration);
            if (pid == null)
            {

                nv.fkPID = null;
            }
            else
            {
                nv.fkPID = intpid;
            }
            nv.fkVTID = visitid;
            nv.fkVisitStatus = 1;


       
            context.Table_Visit.Add(nv);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var thisvisit = context.View_Visit.Where(x => x.fkDocID == docid && x.SDate == nv.SDate && x.EDate == nv.EDate).SingleOrDefault();


            var idText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(thisvisit.pkID.ToString());
            var encryptedid = Convert.ToBase64String(MachineKey.Protect(idText, "Bayramali296"));
            thisvisit.hashid = encryptedid;

            return Json(new { status = 1, thisvisit = nv }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: i find probelam. if (pid == " ")       nv.fkVisitStatus = 10;